# How to make a section show the selected row's information?

Tags: pega

I have got an UI with two sections.
The first section contains a repeat grid layout.
The last one is a section with detailed information about selected grid's row.

I need to provide a feature to select rows using "Up" and "Down" keys (press "Up" - one element above, "Down" - one bellow). And the section with information must be refreshed.
I managed to develop a feature of focusing leveraging Up/Down keys.
But I have got an interesting bug: the next row is selected, but the section is refreshed and show info about previous row.

Here is an example of the actiion configuration:
[image]

The issue is still unresolved.

Comment: Please, if you find out any grammar mistakes, point them out in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled to find out an out-of-box solution, but I realized that Pega doesn't provide any.

 My bug happens because the section refreshes when the previous element is selected. 

 And after refreshing it jumps to the next element. I performed many variants and found out that I can't change the order.

 The only way to provide this is to code custom handler.

Comment: I didn't accomplish that task because my customer refused this one.

Answer (score 0):

Create action set "focus" on the list item and set refresh section there. Refresh should happen on focus on next row.